# Proof Greatest Common Divisor

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Question: Let $m, n, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\operatorname{gcd}(m, n) = 1 = \operatorname{gcd}(n, k)$

Determine if it is true that necessarily $\operatorname{gcd}(m, k) = 1$.

Answer: The statement is FALSE.

Proof : [By Contradiction]

Let $m=3,
  n=5,
  k=6$.

The $\operatorname{gcd}(3,5)=1=\operatorname{gcd}(5,6)$
 , then the $\operatorname{gcd}(3,6)\neq1$
 .

Hence, the statement is FALSE.

Comment: Your proof is ok. You could even set $k=m$ !

Comment: It's not exactly a proof by contraduction (= *reductio ad absurdum*). It's only a *counter-example* (which is well enough, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. Another example would be $m=k=2$ and $n=1$.